# Ember.js: how to render a template and connect it with a specific View

Tags: templates, ember.js, rendering

Inside one of my routes I render a couple of templates as follows:

```
Sp.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        this.render('index');

        this.render('rotatable', {into: 'index', outlet: 'config'}) ;
        this.render('clickable', {into: 'rotatable', outlet: 'front'}) ;
        this.render('configitem', {into: 'clickable'}) ;
        this.render('configuration', {into: 'rotatable', outlet: 'back'}) ;
    ....
```

I have a view called ConfigMenuItemView like

```
Sp.ConfigMenuItemView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'configitem',
    ...
```

However, when I render the **configitem** template, it doesn't connect with my ConfigMenuItemView. Only if I give them idententical names (with the templates' first character being lowercase) it works. Is there a way to tell the render function to which View to connect ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work, use the view name instead of template name as first argument to `this.render`. Since you've defined a templateName property on the view itself ember will use that when rendering the view. So:

```
this.render('configMenuItem', {into: 'clickable'}) ;
```

should work.